# How to (programmatically or by other means) encrypt or protect customer data

Tags: django, postgresql, security, encryption, privacy

I am working on a web project and I want to (as far as possible) handle user data in a way that reduces damage to the users privacy in case of someone compromising our servers/databases.

Of course we only have user dat'a that is needed for the website to do it's job but because of the nature of the project we have quite a bit of information on our users (part of the functionality is to apply yourself to jobs and sending your cv with it)

We thought about encrypting/decrypting sensitive data with a private/public keypair of which the private key is encrypted with the users password but found some security and implementation problems with that :P

the question is how do you implement user privacy and a protection against data theft on centralised web sever with browser compatible protocols while for functionality it is required that users can exchange sensible data?

To give some additional insight: this project is not yet in production stage so there is still time to make things right.

we are already doing some basic stuff like

- serving https
- enforcing https for sites that may handle sensitive data
- hashing salted passwords
- some hardening of our server and services on it
- encrypted harddrives to prevent someone from reading all client information after stealing our servers / harddrives

but that's about it, there is besides the password hashes no mechanism that would stop/at least make it harder for someone who managed to get into (part of) the server to gain all data on all our users. Nor do we see a way to encrypt user data to disable our self from reading them as we need the data (we wouldn't have collected it otherwise) for some part of the website / the functionality we want it to provide. Even if we for example managed somehow (maybe with some javascript) that all data would get to us encrypted (by the client's browser) and we serve the client his privatekey encrypted with some passphrase (like for example his login password) we could not for examle scan user uploaded files for viruses and the like. On the other hand would a client side encryption at least with the browser/webserver concept leave some issues with security at least as we imagine it (you are welcome to prove me wrong) and seems quite like reinventing the wheel, and maybe as this project is not primarily about privacy, but rather privacy is a prefarable property we might not want to reinvent the wheel for it. I strongly believe I am not the first webdeveloper thinking about this, am I? So what have other projects done? What have you done to try to protect your users data?

if relevant we are using django and postrgreSQL for most things and javascript for some UI

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: sorry I did not know such a site existed! Thank You for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to deal with this issue is to split (partition) your data.

Keep minimal data on the Internet-facing web server and pass any sensitive data as quickly as possible to another server that is kept inside a second firewall. Often, data is *pulled* from the web server by the internal secure server to further increase security. This is how banks and finance houses handle sensitive data from the internet (or at least they *should*). There is even a set of standards (PCI) that cover the secure handling of credit card transactions that explain all of this in mind-numbing detail.

To further secure the internal server, you can put it on a separate network and secure physical access to it. You can also focus other security tools on it such as Data Loss Protection and Intrusion Protection.

In addition, if you have any data that *you* don't need to see in the clear, use a client-side encryption library to encrypt it locally. There are still risks of course since the users workstation might be compromised by malware but it still removes risks during data transmission and from server storage risks. It also puts responsibility onto the user rather than just on to your central servers.

You already seem to be a long way ahead of most web developers in ensuring that your customers are kept safe and secure. One other small change it would be worth considering would be to turn on enforced HTTPS for all transactions with your site. That way, there is very little chance of unexpected data leakage such as data being unexpectedly cached.

UPDATE:

Client side encryption can help a lot since it puts the encryption responsibility on the user. Check out LastPass for example. Without doing the encryption client-side, you could never trust the service. Similarly with backup services where you set your key locally so that the backups can never be unlocked by someone on the server - they never have the key.

Partitioning is one of the primary methods for enterprises to secure services that have Internet facing components. As I said, typically, the secure server PULLs data from the less secure one so the less secure server can never have any access to anything more secure even if fully compromised. Indeed there will be a firewall that prevents any traffic from the DMZ (where the less secure service is located) getting to the secure network. Only connections from the secure side are allowed through and they will be tightly controlled by security processes. In a typical bank or other high security setting, you may well find several layers like this, each of which having separate security controls, all partitioned from each other enforcing separation of data and security.

Hope that adds some clarity. Continue to ask if not!

UPDATE 2:

Even for simple, low cost setups, I would still recommend partitioning. For a low cost version, consider having two virtual servers with the dedicated firewall replaced by careful control of the software firewall on the more secure server. Follow the same principals outlined above for everything else.

Comment: Hey Thank you, I really like your answer and would like to upvote it but I haven't got any reputation yet to do so?

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct by clicking on the tick if you like it - And a little bonus for you :) Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I always thought client side encryption to be a bad idea as it can be manipulated/disabled on the client side. Like described in this [article](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/)

How does partitioning the data really improve security? The servers still need to transfer the data in some way so if someone compromised the webserver couldn't they just request the data from the secure server (mimicking the valid communnication between the 2 servers)?

Comment: so what would your advice be for a startup that cannot afford just yet to have a setup like a bank?